# I can't get GridView's RowDataBound update rows after the first row?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Helo Experts again.

I have asked a question similar to this in the past. I was able to resolve it by removing gvRowDataBound completely from the code. This is similar code except I can't remove gvRowDataBound sub.

The issue is that when you click the Edit button of the first row, it allows you to successfully update that row.

After the first row, if you click on thr edit button of any other row, enter the value to update, it doesn't update that row.

Instead, the cursor moves down to the next row.

I didn't design this and having difficulty figuring out what needs to change.

I would really, really appreciate your help.

Thanks SO much in advance.

Here is the sub that is giving me fits. I can provide additional info if needed

```
Protected Sub gvRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim drv As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem
        Dim nameid As String = drv("empl_first").ToString & Space(5) & drv("empl_last").ToString & Space(5) & Space(5) & drv("employee_ID").ToString
        If tmpEmplID <> drv("employee_ID").ToString Then
            tmpEmplID = drv("employee_ID").ToString
            Dim tbl As Table = e.Row.Parent
            If Not IsDBNull(tbl) Then
                Dim row As New GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal)
                Dim cell As New TableCell
                cell.ColumnSpan = Me.GridView1.Columns.Count

                cell.Width = Unit.Percentage(100)
                cell.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold")
                cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#c0c0c0")
                cell.Style.Add("color", "white")

                Dim span As New HtmlGenericControl("span")
                'span.InnerHtml = "Employee ID:    " & nameid & Space(10)

                If drv("date_stamp_appr").ToString = "" Then
                    span.InnerHtml += " <input type='button' ID='" & tmpEmplID & "' value='Approve' onclick='GetHere(""" & tmpEmplID & """)'></input>"
                Else
                    span.InnerHtml += " <b>APPROVED ON: " & drv("date_stamp_appr").ToString & "</b>"
                End If
                Dim linkBtn As LinkButton = CType(e.Row.Cells.Item(0).Controls.Item(2), LinkButton)
                linkBtn.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to   delete this entry?');"

                cell.Controls.Add(span)
                row.Cells.Add(cell)

                tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, row)

            End If

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the RowEditing event for the GridView instead of the RowDatabound event.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response but it is not working. Doing exactly as described above. Is there anyway to rework this-: tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, row). Once it is commented, it works as expected but the word Approve disappears. I am so stressed. Any help would really, really be uplifting.

Comment: Can anyone please help? All the code is supposed to do is list clients based on the dept their supervisor belongs to. I would like to rewrite it. There is an edit/delete keys. Finally, there is a button called Approved. Anytime the supervisor clicks this button, then a date is inserted into the db and the Approved button disappears. I can handle the code that shows supervisor's dept, and all those who belong in that dept. I can make the delete/update work. I just need help with the approved button showing. I can really use some help. Thanks

Comment: Is the date in question part of the select statement for the data source of this gridview?